# Finding a quadratic equation given range and vertex to origin distance

Tags: quadratics

The question :

"Find the equation of quadratic function that value positive for $-7 < x < 1$ and the distance of vertex and origin is 5"

I've just tried to let $-7$ and $1$ are the $x$-intercepts, however, nothing works. Could someone help me, please?

Comment: have you tried multiplying the quadratic by some number to scale it?

Comment: I don't know how to do that, could you please explain it further?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use vertex form of the quadratic function which is given by,

$y - k = a(x-h)^2$.

Given $y$ is positive for $-7 \lt x \lt 1$, we take these points where the function $y$ turns from positive to negative.

Equating $y$ to zero, we have $x = h \pm \sqrt{-\frac {k}{a}}$

Solving, $h - \sqrt{-\frac {k}{a}} = - 7$ and $h + \sqrt{-\frac {k}{a}} = 1$

$h = -3, -\frac{k}{a} = 16$

As $h^2 + k^2 = 25, k = \pm4$ We know the function is positive for $x \in (-7,1)$ so $k = 4$.

$a = -\frac{1}{4}$.

The equation of quadratic is $y = -\frac{1}{4} (x+3)^2 + 4$

Comment: Could you tell me where did you find that formula? I mean that $y - k = a(x - h)^2$?

Comment: A quadratic function is $y = ax^2 + bx +c$. You can convert that in the form $y-k = a(x-h)^2$. $y = a(x^2 + \frac{b}{a} x) + c$. Then convert to $y = a(x+\frac{b}{2a})^2 + c - \frac{b^2}{4a}$. So instead you can write it as above.

Comment: Here is a link https://www.khanacademy.org/math/algebra/x2f8bb11595b61c86:quadratic-functions-equations/x2f8bb11595b61c86:vertex-form/v/vertex-form-intro

Answer (score 2):

So a quadratic with roots at $1$ and $\mbox{-}7$ will be $c(x+7)(x-1)$, where $c$ is a real number. We just have to figure out what $c$ should be. We need $c$ to be negative if you want the function to be positive on only $(\mbox{-}7,1)$. Also, here the vertex is the point $\left(\mbox{-}\dfrac{b}{2a},f\left(\mbox{-}\dfrac{b}{2a}\right)\right)$. Let's write $\mbox{-}t$ for our number $c$ (so t will be positive), so our polynomial will be:

$$f(x)=c(x^2+6x-7)=cx^2+6cx-7c$$

To find what c is, we assume that the distance between the vertex and the origin is $5$ as desired. Compute the vertex of $f(x)$:

$$-\frac{b}{2a} = -\frac{6c}{2c} = -3$$

$$f(-\frac{b}{2a}) = f(-3) = c((-3)^2 + 6(-3) - 7) = c(9 -18-7) = -16c$$

which is what it means for the vertex to be:

$$v = \bigg(-\frac{b}{2a},f(-\frac{b}{2a})\bigg) = (-3,-16c)$$

The distance between the vertex and the origin being 5 means that:

$$5 = \sqrt{(-3-0)^2+(-16c-0)^2} =\sqrt{9 + 256c^2}$$

solving for c gives $c=\dfrac{\mbox{-}1}{4}$ (there are two solutions but we need the negative one like I stated).

Comment: Oh, so that's how it should be, anyway thank you so much

Comment: Done, fair enough.